# Samsung smart-tv jquery simplemodal scroll

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, samsung-smart-tv

Samsung smart-tv application that uses simplemodal jquery plugin

when i click on a link it popups simplemodal and inside of it there are some elements that has the following structure

```
<div class="update"> contents </div>
```

my problem is that i am trying to scroll this modal using the remote control

so i have a function that handel keydown events .. and i use the following logic

```
if(cur.next is not empty)
    cur.removeclass(active)
    cur.next.addclass(active)
    $(".simplemodal-warp").animate({scrollTop:$(".active").offset().top},0);
```

but the modal scrolling like this goes all over the place ! it does not function like expected ..

logic of removing active class and activating the next one is functioning properly

when i press down on the remote current active element is deactivated and the next one is activated , but position animation is not working i tried to use position instead of offset and it didn't help either it scrolls to the top of the element . then when i press down again it scrolls with an offset that is less than the previous one
then when i press again it scrolls to an offset that is bigger than the last one , and so on  like this

1
5
3
8
7
13
9
16

! crazy output ! , any help about that ?

Comment: Buy me an Samsung smart-TV first, then I will help you :P

Answer (score 0):

Use animate marginLeft, marginTop and so on. It will run the animation correctly!